# Why can't the particular solution have factors found in the general homogeneous equation in it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential equation:

$$y''-4y'+4y = g(x)$$

The general solution of the homogeneous equation is $e^{2x}(C_1+ xC_2)$. 
Find the particular solution when $g(x) = e^{2x}$ and $g(x)=e^{-2x}$.

When $g(x)= e^{2x}$, why can't $y_{p_2}=Be^{2x}$ or $y_{p_2}=Bxe^{2x}$? I see that they are both part of the general homogeneous equation, but why is this a limitation?

Comment: Have you tried substituting those terms in and seeing what happens when you do? Since the solve the homogeneous equation they automatically give zero, and can't help you to build the inhomogeneous part.

Comment: When solving for the particular solutions you want to throw something in for $y$ into the left hand side $y''-4y'+4y$ and you are hoping to get out some nonzero thing, which is equal to $g(x)$ but since those solutions are solutions of the homogeneous equation then you will necessarily get zero when you throw them into $y''-4y'+4y$ and this will not be equal to $g(x)$ and not a solution of the nonhomogeneous equation.

Comment: This is a good lesson in that the solutions of the homogeneous equation will effect how you will approach solving the nonhomogeneous equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just because, *by definition* of the solutions of the homogeneous equation, the left-hand side is $0$ when we set $y(x)=\mathrm e^{2x}$  or  $y(x)=x\mathrm e^{2x}$. Hence the l.h.s. can't be $\mathrm e^{2x}$.

In that case you have to find a particular solution of the form; $\;Bx^2\mathrm e^{2x}$. More generally, if the r.h.s. has the form $\,p(x)\mathrm e^{2x}$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, a particular solution is $x^2q(x)\mathrm e^{2x}$, where $q(x)$ is another polynomial of degree $d$.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, we must first examine the associated homogeneous DE

$$y''-4y'+4y=0$$

which has characteristic polynomial

$$p(r)=r^2-4r+4$$
$$\Rightarrow \ p(r)=(r-2)^2$$
and thus the characteristic polynomial has a root of 2 with multiplicity 2. This means our fundamental set for the homogeneous DE is
$$H=\lbrace e^{2x}, xe^{2x} \rbrace$$
Now, if you're looking for a particular solution, you cannot have any linear combinations of these, or else it's not a particular solution! We already know the general solution is of the form 
$$y=y_h+y_p$$
Where $y_h$ is the solution to your associated homogeneous ($y=C_1e^{2x}+C_2xe^{2x}$), and $y_p$ a particular solution.
Thus, including elements from $H$ in the particular solution does nothing towards helping you find a particular solution! Counting elements of $H$ again when you've already included an arbitrary constant in front of them adds nothing; in essence, think of the particular solution as "the thing satisfying the DE when I make all the $C$'s$=0$"

Hopefully that explains in an intuitive way why "the limitation" exists on what can be a particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following differential equation:
$$y''+2y'=3+4\sin(2x)$$
What is the solution?